# For automake: How to execute a command in the configure.ac?

Tags: makefile, configure, autoconf, automake

In the automake

I want to assign to a Makefile variable a command execution result

How to do it in the **configure.ac**?

Comment: When does the command execution happen? When `configure` is run or when `make` is run?

Answer (score 6):

To assign the output of `echo foo` to the variable `var`  (ie, `var=foo`),
put this in `configure.ac`:

```
AC_SUBST([var],[$( echo foo )])  # use backticks for maximal portability
```

Or, assign var and then invoke `AC_SUBST([var])`  (with no second argument).